# gnuplot - generate missing x-values

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Say I have a list of y-values without corresponding x-values but I do know that the measurements occur in a fixed interval (say, every second). How do I create the x-values to plot them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the zeroth column, which contains the row number:

```
plot "file.txt" using 0:1
```

(This is equivalent to omitting the `using` statement when plotting a single column file). But now you see that you can perform any calculation on `$0`:

```
plot "file.txt" using ($0 * 5):1
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Which simply means that you have a single column file. Then you can simply plot it as usual:

```
plot "file.txt"
```

The corresponding `x` values are then simply taken to be `1, 2, 3, ...`

Comment: lol, I've grown so accustomed to having all necessary data in the data file I completely forgot about that. thank you.

Comment: what if I have measurements "every 5 seconds" or so, though?

Comment: I don't think there is any straightforward solution to this. You can easily create such column though using bash or python for example.